# How to highlight the search text in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to highlight the search text .I got lot of link

The best example is that .
https://github.com/nmartynenko/jquery-search-plugin
Now i need to implement the best way in my example but it is not working,
Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/SCfPQ/

```
 var searcher = $("#realTimeContents").search({
                searchType: "highlightSelected",
                searchSelector : "div",
                scrollTo : true
            });

            //make sure we find the same text, otherwise clear search postions
            function find(up) {
                var currentText = searcher.getText();

                var text = $(".textSearchvalue_h").val();
                alert(text);


                if (text != currentText) {
                    searcher.setText(text);
                  //  alert(getConcurrencesNumber());

                }

                searcher.nextConcurrence(up);
            }

            //bind events
            $("#prev").click(function(e) {
                alert("pre")
                e.preventDefault();

                find(true);
            });

            $("#next").click(function(e) {
                alert("next")
                e.preventDefault();

                find(false);
            });
              $("#search").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                find(true);
            });
```

Comment: what do you mean hightlight?

Comment: like in chrome i suppose

Comment: actually i am not able to import that..

Comment: actually i need for ipad, yes i need like chrome like we use contr+F